# C#, invoke anonymous method (Action<>) from background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, anonymous-methods

This should be simple!

I want to create an anonymous Action<> delegate to perform a GUI update, which I will call from several other anonymous delegates (which will be run on separate threads).

```
    void Test() {

        Action<string> invokeDisplay = new Action<string>(delegate(string Element) {
            //Do a variety of things to my GUI depending on Element parameter
        });


        MethodInvoker opLong1 = new MethodInvoker(delegate() {

        //  Do long task

            this.Invoke(invokeDisplay("long1"));
        });

        MethodInvoker opLong2 = new MethodInvoker(delegate() {

        //  Do long task

            this.Invoke(invokeDisplay("long2"));
        });

        new Thread(new ThreadStart(opLong1)).Start();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(opLong2)).Start();
    }
```

So whats the correct syntax for this line?

```
            this.Invoke(invokeDisplay("long1"));
```

Comment: Which GUI? WinForms, WPF, jQuery?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => invokeDisplay("long1")));` will work.

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken That's way more work than it needs to be...

Comment: @Servy Ah yeah, I forgot there was an overload of `Invoke` that takes parameters.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, it worked, but ill always take the shortest road :)

Comment: and actually, I've learned abit more about lamdba feeds, so thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
Invoke(action, "long1");
```

The delegate is the first parameter, and the argument(s) you want to pass to it follow.

Comment: Thats the one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another available option:

```
this.Invoke((Action)(() => invokeDisplay("long1")));
```